# Vacuously truth in linguistics

Tags: truth

I'm wondering because according to dictionaries, there's no truth value in it, but according to Wiki, it's a vacuous truth.

**the possibility in certain semantic systems of a statement being neither true nor false while also not being determinately of any third truth-value, as all my children are asleep uttered by a childless person**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/truth-value-gap

**"All my children are goats" is a vacuous truth, when spoken by someone without children.**

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: It is same true in linguistics.... But unlike in math/logic/computer science, in linguistic/real life we tend to care only about relevant truths... (Since "there are" infinite irrelevant truths..(for a particular meat ball))

Comment: @xerx593 I've revised the post a little.

Comment: Because dictionary.com refers to "certain semantic systems" and Wikipedia refers to standard classical logic. In "certain semantic systems", [Kripke's](https://iep.utm.edu/liar-paradox/#SH3c), for example, one can have truth-value gaps and make vacuous sentences fall into them. However, this is rarely done since vacuous truths do not cause many problems, and gaps are reserved for trickier purposes, like vagueness and paradoxes.

Comment: In everyday life, we do not say "All my children are goats" when I've no children... That's all.

Answer (score 1):

A practical reason why vacuous truths are avoided in everyday speech is that  they present too much scope for confusion, since they are superficially indistinguishable from non-vacuous claims.

Suppose I sent you the message 'the burglars in your house have found your safe'. How would you know whether it was a vacuously true statement referring to the absence of burglars in your house, or a true statement requiring you to call the police? Mind you, if we did recognise such statement as conventionally true, I might have had a better outcome to my insurance fraud case:

Judge: 'Are you asking us to believe that all the priceless works of art in your house were destroyed in the fire?'

Self, with hand on heart: 'I can assure you, it is true, my lord'.

Comment: Maybe the judge could clarify the situation by asking "Were any priceless works of art destroyed in the fire?" Or perhaps "Which specific works of art were destroyed in the fire?" or maybe "What is the value of the priceless works of art that were destroyed in the fire?" Then your answer could safely be classified as misleading, rather than vacuous. That would certainly keep the insurance company happy.

Comment: Are "vacuously true" and "just true" different?

Comment: @LudwigV good point. But could I not answer 'All those in my house were', 'The Rembrandt portrait of the first Duke of Ocram' (etc, mentioning non-existent paintings) '£500million', as all of those statements would be vacuously true.

Comment: So you ring up an expert and ask how much the Rembrandt portrait... is worth. The answer would have to be that no value can be attributed to it. Then it would indeed be priceless, but not in the way intended. I just want to see a difference between these cases and old-fashioned analytic propositions, though I suppose there is some difference between "vacuous" and "trivial"

Comment: @LudwigV in complete honesty I could say to his lordship the judge that the expert I rang said the Rembrandt was worth ten million, which would be vacuously true if I hadn't actually called an expert, or indeed if I had called someone who was not an expert.

Comment: Interesting. I think that answer would be false. Even if it is true, or not false, how would you answer the question how much you paid for it?

Comment: @LudwigV great question! If a vacuous truth is of the form x verb something, where x does not exist, then perhaps I could in vacuous truth say 'the amount I paid was £10million'.

Comment: Very good! The problem is about failed references. "The amount I paid" is a referring expression (because of "the"). However, your response is false because you did not pay £10 million; you paid £0. Note that there is no referring expression in those sentences. So the amount you paid is £0. The two sentences answer the same question, so they need to give the same answer. It is often a mistake to rely on surface grammar.

Comment: @LudwigV that was a great gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

Take the statement *if A then B*.

If *A is FALSE* then *if A then B* is vacuous: B can be anything as it is never evaluated. This is nasty: the statement cannot be false, but it isn't really true either, which is why we need this third 'vacuous' option.

Suppose a *reductio ad absurdam* proof starts with *if A then B*. We then show *B is FALSE*. It follows that *A is false*. Is *if A then B* vacuous? I think it must be, but it is not as bad as a regular vacuous statements as *B* had to be *FALSE* to prove *A* was *FALSE*.

True statements can include a vacuous case. Suppose you have a meter that reads mobile phone signals. It reads zero, so you know all mobile phones are off. There may be no mobile phones nearby, but the statement is still true. 'No mobile phone is on' is an equivalent statement without the vacuous case and it is also true.

We do not produce vacuous statements in normal speech, and we do not expect it from others. "All my children are goats" sounds like an absurd truth. If the speaker had no children, then that statement is not false, but it is only 'vacuously true'. Vacuous statements can be a sophist's trick to avoid making a demonstrably false statements. If someone makes one, they are probably up to no good.